# How to add into an arraylist and lookup using binarysearch? PhoneBook ArrayList clas

Tags: java, arraylist

I have to do a PhoneBook class. I have done all but two methods. I need some help on how to do them. 
1.  A PhoneEntry class exists. =
a.  Write a PhoneBook class  that stores PhoneEntry objects.  Add the following methods.
iii.    addInOrder(PhoneEntry a)  This is the insertion Sort
v.  lookup(String name)- return the phone number associated with name. Use binary search

I don't know how to do both of them. I have some of addInOrder done but none of lookup. This is what I have so far:

```
public void addInOrder(PhoneEntry a) {
    for (int outer = 1; outer < book.size(); outer++) {
        int position = outer;
        String key = (a.get(position);
        // shift larger values to right
        while (position > 0 && a.get(position - 1).compareTo(key) > 0) {
            (a.get(position)).equals(a.get(position - 1));
            position--;
        }

        a.get(position).equals(key);
    }
}

public String lookUp(String name) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
addInOrder
```

Just add at the end of the entries then sort if performance is not relevant or you have few elements (you can easily sort using `Collections.sort`). A faster approach is to keep the entries sorted from the beginning so finding where to add is faster.

```
lookup
```

Iterate over all the entries, check each name and return the phone if equal. A faster approach is to keep a Map where the key is the name.